Bluetooth BLE on ESP32, re-adverstising / re-connecting does not work in some cases
i am working on a bluetooth BLE connection between 2 or more ESP32-S3 (wroom).
At the moment there are one BLE Server and 2 BLE clients.
I am sending some bytes from the server to all the clients as a broadcast to sync some action between them.
This works really well... but when the server shuts down and restarts, the clients wont re-connect again. the client is scanning again for BLE devices and is listing the found devices but it doesnt find the server anymore.
the cases:

server starts first -> then client starts -> connection works
server starts first -> then client starts -> connection works -> client disconnects / restarts  -> connection works
server starts first -> then client starts -> connection works -> server disconnects / restarts  -> NO RE-CONNECT
client starts first -> then server starts -> connection works
client starts first -> then server starts -> connection works -> client disconnects / restarts  -> connection works
client starts first -> then server starts -> connection works -> server disconnects / restarts  -> NO RE-CONNECT

i am struggling for hours now and i am not finding the reason.
Would be great if someone could take a look at the source.
this is the main.cpp:
#include <Arduino.h>
//#define THIS_IS_THE_MIDI_PROXY

#ifdef THIS_IS_THE_MIDI_PROXY
    #include "midiProxyBLEserver.h"
#else
    #include "BLE_client.h"
#endif

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(500); // Time for serial port to work?

    //=== MIDI PROXY AUFSETZEN =====
    #ifdef THIS_IS_THE_MIDI_PROXY
        midiProxy_initialize_BLE();
    #else
        BLE_client_initialize();
    #endif
}

void loop() {
    //=== MIDI PROXY AUFSETZEN =====
    #ifdef THIS_IS_THE_MIDI_PROXY
        midiProxy_midiLoop();
    #else
        BLE_client_Loop();
    #endif
}

the code for the server (midiProxyBLEserver.h):
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>

class MyServerCallbacks : public BLEServerCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEServer *pServer);
    void onDisconnect(BLEServer *pServer);
};
void midiProxy_initialize_BLE();
void sendValuepairToListeners(byte midiInCC, byte midiInValue);
void midiProxy_midiLoop();

the code for the server (midiProxyBLEserver.cpp):
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLE2902.h>
//---------------------------

#define SERVICE_UUID        "204916ff-8db3-4368-bab9-e1f6e1ad653c"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "f2e030f2-8c2b-46b6-bbab-5cf9dd837962"
//---------------------------

BLEServer *pServer = NULL;
BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = NULL;
uint32_t anzahl_BLE_devices;
bool aDeviceConnected = false;
bool aDeviceDISconnected = false;

class MyServerCallbacks : public BLEServerCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEServer *pServer) {
        aDeviceConnected = true;
    };

    void onDisconnect(BLEServer *pServer) {
        aDeviceDISconnected = true;
    }
};

void midiProxy_initialize_BLE() {
    BLEDevice::init("ESP32");               // Create the BLE Device
    pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();    // Create the BLE Server
    pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());
    BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);    // Create the BLE Service
    pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(               // Create a BLE Characteristic
        CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
        BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ | 
        BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE | 
        BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY | 
        BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE
    );

     // Create a BLE Descriptor
    pCharacteristic->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

    // Start the service
    pService->start();

    // Start advertising
    BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
    pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
    pAdvertising->setScanResponse(false);
    pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x0);  // set value to 0x00 to not advertise this parameter
    BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
    
    Serial.println("Waiting a client connection to notify...");
}

void sendValuepairToListeners(byte midiInCC, byte midiInValue) {
    uint8_t byteArray[2];
    byteArray[0] = midiInCC;
    byteArray[1] = midiInValue;
    pCharacteristic->setValue((uint8_t *)&byteArray, 2);
    pCharacteristic->notify();
}

void midiProxy_midiLoop() {
    if (aDeviceConnected) {
        anzahl_BLE_devices = pServer->getConnectedCount();
        Serial.println("CONNECT! - clients connected: " + String(anzahl_BLE_devices));  // TODO: scheint immer erst im nächsten loop korrekt zu sein!?    
        BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
        aDeviceConnected = false;
    }

    if (aDeviceDISconnected) {
        anzahl_BLE_devices = pServer->getConnectedCount();
        Serial.println("DISCONNECT! - clients connected: " + String(anzahl_BLE_devices));   // TODO: scheint immer erst im nächsten loop korrekt zu sein!?     
        BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
        aDeviceDISconnected = false;
    }
}

the code for the client (BLE_client.h):
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "BLEDevice.h"

class MyAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks : public BLEAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks {
    void onResult(BLEAdvertisedDevice advertisedDevice);
};
void OnScanResults(BLEScanResults scanResults);
void initialize_Device();
void set_values();
void scan();
void BLE_client_initialize();
class MyClientCallback : public BLEClientCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEClient *pclient);
    void onDisconnect(BLEClient *pclient);
};
bool connectToServer();
void BLE_client_Loop();

the code for the client (BLE_client.cpp):
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "BLEDevice.h"
//----------------------------

static BLEUUID serviceUUID("204916ff-8db3-4368-bab9-e1f6e1ad653c");
static BLEUUID charUUID("f2e030f2-8c2b-46b6-bbab-5cf9dd837962");

BLEScan *pBLEScan;
static boolean doConnect = false;
static boolean connected = false;
static boolean isScanning = false;  // True if scan started or false if there was an error.
static BLERemoteCharacteristic *pRemoteCharacteristic;
static BLEAdvertisedDevice *myDevice;
volatile bool newValuesReceivedFromProxy = false;
//----------------------------

/**
 * Scan for BLE servers and find the first one that advertises the service we are looking for.
 */
class MyAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks : public BLEAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks {
    /**
     * Called for each advertising BLE server.
     */
    void onResult(BLEAdvertisedDevice advertisedDevice) {
        Serial.print("BLE Advertised Device found: ");
        Serial.println(advertisedDevice.toString().c_str());

        // We found a device, let us now see if it contains the service we are looking for.
        if (advertisedDevice.haveServiceUUID() && advertisedDevice.isAdvertisingService(serviceUUID)) {
            Serial.print("BLE: Found our server!");
            BLEDevice::getScan()->stop();
            isScanning = false;

            myDevice = new BLEAdvertisedDevice(advertisedDevice);
            doConnect = true;   // scan succesfull ... now connect to service            
        }  
    }  
}; 

void OnScanResults(BLEScanResults scanResults) {
    Serial.println("BLE Scan finished!");
    isScanning = false;
 }

void initialize_Device() {
    Serial.println("Starting BLE Client ...");
    BLEDevice::init("");    
} 

void set_values() {
    pBLEScan = BLEDevice::getScan();
    pBLEScan->setAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks(new MyAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks());
    pBLEScan->setInterval(1349);
    pBLEScan->setWindow(449);
    pBLEScan->setActiveScan(true);
} 

void scan() {
    pBLEScan->start(10, &OnScanResults, true);
    isScanning = true;
} 

void BLE_client_initialize() { 
    initialize_Device();
    set_values();
    scan();
}

class MyClientCallback : public BLEClientCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEClient *pclient) {
        Serial.println("onConnect");
    }
    void onDisconnect(BLEClient *pclient) {
        connected = false;
        Serial.println("onDisconnect");
    }
};

bool connectToServer() {
    Serial.print("Forming a connection to ");
    Serial.println(myDevice->getAddress().toString().c_str());

    BLEClient *pClient = BLEDevice::createClient();
    pClient->setClientCallbacks(new MyClientCallback());
    Serial.println(" - Created client");

    // Connect to the remote BLE Server.
    pClient->connect(myDevice);  // if you pass BLEAdvertisedDevice instead of address, it will be recognized type of peer device address (public or private)
    pClient->setMTU(517);  //set client to request maximum MTU from server (default is 23 otherwise)
    Serial.println(" - Connected to server");

    // Obtain a reference to the service we are after in the remote BLE server.
    BLERemoteService *pRemoteService = pClient->getService(serviceUUID);
    if (pRemoteService == nullptr) {
        Serial.print("Failed to find our service UUID: ");
        Serial.println(serviceUUID.toString().c_str());
        pClient->disconnect();
        return false;
    }
    Serial.println(" - Found our service");

    // Obtain a reference to the characteristic in the service of the remote BLE server.
    pRemoteCharacteristic = pRemoteService->getCharacteristic(charUUID);
    if (pRemoteCharacteristic == nullptr) {
        Serial.print("Failed to find our characteristic UUID: ");
        Serial.println(charUUID.toString().c_str());
        pClient->disconnect();
        return false;
    }
    Serial.println(" - Found our characteristic");

    // Read the value of the characteristic.
    if (pRemoteCharacteristic->canRead()) {
        std::string value = pRemoteCharacteristic->readValue();
        Serial.print("The characteristic value was: ");
        Serial.println(value.c_str());
    }

    if (pRemoteCharacteristic->canNotify()) {
    //     pRemoteCharacteristic->registerForNotify(notifyCallback);
    }

    connected = true;
    return true;
}

void BLE_client_Loop() {

    if (doConnect == true) {
        if (connectToServer()) {
            Serial.println("We are now connected to the BLE Server.");
        } 
        else {
            Serial.println("We have failed to connect to the server; there is nothing more we will do.");
        }
        doConnect = false;
    }

    // If we are connected to a peer BLE Server
    if (connected) {   
        
        if (newValuesReceivedFromProxy) {
            // ... do something ...
        }
    } 
     
    if (!connected && !isScanning) {
        Serial.println("Scanning for 10 seconds ...");
        set_values();   // TODO: eigentlich quatsch .... ganz unten müsste reichen
        scan();
    }
}

There must be a Bug in my code, so that the server does not re-Advertise after a disconnect from a client... but i cant find it...
I am happy if someone could help!
Thanks a lot and have a happy new year !!! :)
bye
andre

Have you tried a different method of checking if your server starts advertising again? There are various apps for mobile phones that can be used to debug BLE, like LightBlue or nRF Connect.

when i think about it again ... should be a problem on the client, right? a running client can not reconnect to a server that temporarily disconnected ..?
i will try one of the apps.... thanks for the hint
